# iFrame linking in Modal - Switching the iFrame (Keeping the same Modal Up) +++

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, modal-dialog

Sample Page.
http://newsite.702wedding.com/live/linktovideo.asp

I need the 4 links to load streaming video feed in the iframe (inside the modal)

what are the line(s) of code? I have looked on the internet, but finding stuff from 2003.

Thanks 4 Help.
I will make sure to Accept any answers that work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving the `iframe` a `name` property, such as:

```
<iframe width="640" height="480" src="live-internet-weddings-intro.asp" name="internal_frame">
```

And setting the `target` of the links:

```
<a href="live-internet-weddings-the-wedding-chapel.asp" target="internal_frame">Las Vegas Wedding Chapels</a>
```

I haven't tested this, it might be deprecated functionality or my details might be slightly off.  If it doesn't work then I have some JavaScript-based ideas as well.